# How do I map undo and redo to ctrl-z and ctrl-y respectively?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm using Neovim on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

If possible, I would like the solution to work both in insert mode and command mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Key mapping is introduced in chapter 5 of the user manual: `:help 05.3`, and this is elaborated upon at `:help 40.1`.

You can use the following for normal mode:

```
nnoremap <C-Z> u
nnoremap <C-Y> <C-R>
```

For insert mode, you still need to run a normal mode command. You can include `<Esc>` in mappings to leave insert mode, but in this case you can also use `<C-O>` to run a single normal mode command while remaining in insert mode (See `:help i_CTRL-O`):

```
inoremap <C-Z> <C-O>u
inoremap <C-Y> <C-O><C-R>
```

For more details, see `:help mapping`.

Comment: Ha! You were faster @Rich . But what exactely will be the effect of the map in insert mode, without delimiting the undo history by exiting insert mode? :/

Comment: @lsrdg The first time you press it, it will undo the *current* insert. Subsequent presses undo previous edits.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I commented while your answer consisted of only the mappings. (:

Comment: @lsrdg No worries! I think it's a legitimate question even after my edits. I wasn't sure what it would do until I tried it!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does the ctrl z mapping work properly, or does the shell get it and do backgrounding job control? I remember reading about an issue with it at one point, and i cant remember which layer gets it first

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble Good question! I only tested in the GUI, but I suspect job control would kick in before Vim gets a change to see the mapping in the terminal.